# How do I combine three cell arrays to make a matrix/table with three columns in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

My first array called removed is a 61 x 1 array, my second array called kept is a 45 x 1 array, my third array called deleted_rxns1 is a 16 x 1 array

I am using;

```
    combo=vertcat(removed, kept, deleted_rxns1)
```

However, this just combines them altogether into one 122 x 1 array. I need three columns one for each of the removed, kept and deleted_rxns1.

I also need to preferably align them via their common row name, and have NA where this doesn't happen. kept have some rows named the same as removed, whilst deleted_rxns1 has some of the same rows names as removed. It would be handy if the final output could look like this;

```
     Removed       Kept        Deleted
       NH3          NA            NH3
       CH4          CH4           NA
       02           02            NA
       C02          NA            CO2
```

If this is not possible, I would still prefer to have a matrix with three columns. Please could anybody help?

Thank-you

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the arrays are not of the same size, you can not concatenate them into a 2D matrix.
You can however, use a similar construction to what you have requested via `cell` arrays:

```
c = {removed, kept, deleted_rxns1}; 
% c{1} == removed
% c{2} == kept
% c{3} == deleted_rxns1
```

As for you second request, you have not provided nearly enough information to classify which rows from each column adhere to each other - so I can't really help until you supply more information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 45 rows of the 45x1 array (kept) correspond to the original removed array, whilst 16 rows of the 16x1 array (deleted_rxns1) correspond to the original removed array.  I would manually need to go through each one, to see what row in each corresponds to the row in the original removed. I wasn't too sure whether there would be an automated function in Matlab, where it would align the values in each column accordingly based on it appearing in the original removed, and where it doesn't put NA, a bit like the example in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that works fine for your toy example:

```
clc;
clear;

% vectors
removed = cellstr(['NH3';'CH4';'O2';'CO2']);
kept = cellstr(['CH4';'O2']);
deleted = cellstr(['NH3';'CO2']);

% match vectors in cell array by columns
M = num2cell(NA*ones(4,3));
M(:,1) = removed;
M(find(ismember(M(:,1),kept)),2) = kept;
M(find(ismember(M(:,1),deleted)),3) = deleted;
```

and then you will get

```
䠜M =
{
  [1,1] = NH3
  [2,1] = CH4
  [3,1] = O2
  [4,1] = CO2
  [1,2] =   NA
  [2,2] = CH4
  [3,2] = O2
  [4,2] =   NA
  [1,3] = NH3
  [2,3] =   NA
  [3,3] =   NA
  [4,3] = CO2
}
```

which looks like
[image]

I ran the code above in Octave, but I believe it should also work in Matlab.